# MySQL connection string for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, mysql-workbench

I have a ASP.NET application running in `VS2008` and i have `ODBC connection in web.config file`.
I am using 64bit Windows 7 machine.
I am trying to connect it with my MYSQL workbench but it shows me the following error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

and i am using the following connection string :

```
add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};server=localhost;User Id=root;database=dbname; providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
```

Please let me know what i am missing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MyODBC which is MyODBC 5.2 in your case.. Or you can use whatever MYODBC Driver is installed.. just change your DRIVER in the connection string accordingly